# Comment dire « I wish I knew (myself) » en français ?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

Par exemple (en anglais),

> What should we do?
>
> I wish I knew.

J'aimerais bien le savoir ? Si seulement je le savais ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your suggestions are fine.

The second one is often simplified in:

> Si je savais...

Answer (score -4):

« J'aimerais bien le savoir. » va bien ; on peut aussi dire « je voudrais bien le savoir. » mais on dit à peu près la même chose.

Cependant, « Si seulement je le savais ! » ne communique pas l'idée du désir de savoir. Je ne l'utiliserais donc pas pour une traduction.

Voici une autre possibilité ;

- Je donnerais cher pour (le) savoir !

Comment: Je n'ai pas mis de vote négatif, mais je pense que l'expression "*si seulement je le savais !*" exprime un réel dépit/regret de ne pas savoir. Donc, par opposition, l'idée, l'envie, le désir de savoir.

Comment: @OneMoreTimeButAnonimously Je suis bien d'accord, la conséquence inévitable sera un *désir* mais ce n'est pas l'idée mise en avant et le TLFi semble confirmer cela : Si seulement + ind Synon. de « si au moins », « si encore ». Pourquoi est-ce que j'y suis venu? Elle ne voulait pas que je monte. Si seulement je l'avais écoutée. Je me lève en sursaut: si seulement je pouvais m'arrêter de penser, ça irait déjà mieux (SARTRE, Nausée, 1938, p. 130). (champ 1/2)

Comment: @OneMoreTimeButAnonimously  Je pense même que cela répond mal à la question « What should we do? ». D'ailleurs on traduit « Si seulement je le savais. » par « If I only knew. ». On peut répliquer : « Eh bien, quoi donc si vous le saviez ? » ; cela montre l'artificialité de la réponse « Si seulement je le savais. », sa caractéristique d'être incomplète ; c'est une expression qui est presque toujours accompagnée par des explications explicites (« ça irait déjà mieux » ci-dessus) ou déduites (elle ne voulait pas que je monte) . (champ 2/2)

Comment: "Si seulement je le savais" convient tout à fait, donc cette réponse est en partie fausse.

Comment: @LaurentS. Il me semble que non ; le dictionnaire dit « synonyme de 'si au moins' je savais » cela ne dit pas « Je voudrais savoir ».